# Devise and Rails 401 Unauthorized with Custom Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have been trying to include user authentication as part of a CMS I am developing and have been having trouble integrating Devise with custom fields. The forms are displaying correctly but when I try to create a new user I get a terminal error of unauthorized and no object is committed to the db.

Using Rails 5.1.4 and Devise 4.3.0

The error I get along with my code:

**Error Message from Terminal**

```
Started PUT "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-28 18:23:36 -0500
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CY2/3DW9B6WYypeIlKtB/mTgNgvViZDw94FIwZGyl0ORcrmoEW1Ez/I0FAnpjZNU8aUd5uRJFOMUyM0azyTipA==", "user"=>{"firstname"=>"firstname", "lastname"=>"lastname", "classyear"=>"WG19", "email"=>"email@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create Account"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:firstname,:lastname,:classyear])
    end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  resources :assets
  resources :departments

  resources :courses do
    member do
      get :new_course_by_department
    end
  end
  root 'pages#index'
end
```

**initalizers/devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  ...
  ...
  config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]
end
```

Comment: Edit and add your sign up form code. Looks like the form is doing a `PUT /users` instead of a `POST /users`.

Comment: Thanks! That was the exact issue, had a put method of the form builder. Much Appreciated!